# Twisted SMTP Server - getting full recipient list, and header data?

Tags: python, smtp, twisted

So after a huge amount of patience from, and gratitude towards @Jean-PaulCalderone, I now have a twisted mail server that supports (yet to be tested) TLS! I can telnet to it, issue my EHLO, MAIL FROM etc etc, and dump the message to file, as per the code snippet below (the 2 classes below are ripped and modified from http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/emailserver.tac:

```
class ConsoleMessageDelivery:
    implements(smtp.IMessageDelivery)

    def receivedHeader(self, helo, origin, recipients):
        by = helo[1]
        from_ = origin
        for_ = "%s" % (' '.join(map(str, recipients)))
        return "Client: %s\nFrom: %s\nTo: %s\n\n" % (by, from_, for_)

    def validateFrom(self, helo, origin):
        return origin

    def validateTo(self, user):
        return lambda: ConsoleMessage()


class ConsoleMessage:
    implements(smtp.IMessage)

    def __init__(self):
        self.lines = []

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        self.lines.append(line)

    def eomReceived(self):
        print "New message received:"
        print "\n".join(self.lines)
        msgFile = open("./test.msg","w")
        msgFile.writelines(self.lines)
        msgFile.close()
        self.lines = None
        return defer.succeed(None)

    def connectionLost(self):
        # There was an error, throw away the stored lines
        self.lines = None
```

However, the problem now arises when I specifiy multiple RCPT TO addresses - only the last one is in "recipients" in my receivedheader method? Am I mishandling this in "receivedHeader"? I'm starting to thing it's the return statement in my validateTo function. The server logs, when I send a single message to 2 recipients looks like this:

```
2014-10-21 08:05:10+0000 [ESMTP,2,127.0.0.1] Receiving message for delivery: from=me@home.com to=['you@work1.com', 'you@work2.com']
2014-10-21 08:05:17+0000 [ESMTP,2,127.0.0.1] New message received:
2014-10-21 08:05:17+0000 [ESMTP,2,127.0.0.1] Client: 127.0.0.1
2014-10-21 08:05:17+0000 [ESMTP,2,127.0.0.1] From: me@home.com
2014-10-21 08:05:17+0000 [ESMTP,2,127.0.0.1] To: you@work1.com
2014-10-21 08:05:17+0000 [ESMTP,2,127.0.0.1]
2014-10-21 08:05:17+0000 [ESMTP,2,127.0.0.1]
2014-10-21 08:05:17+0000 [ESMTP,2,127.0.0.1]
2014-10-21 08:05:17+0000 [ESMTP,2,127.0.0.1]
2014-10-21 08:05:17+0000 [ESMTP,2,127.0.0.1] Today is the 21st Oct
2014-10-21 08:05:17+0000 [ESMTP,2,127.0.0.1] (still)
2014-10-21 08:05:17+0000 [ESMTP,2,127.0.0.1] New message received:
2014-10-21 08:05:17+0000 [ESMTP,2,127.0.0.1] Client: 127.0.0.1
2014-10-21 08:05:17+0000 [ESMTP,2,127.0.0.1] From: me@home.com
2014-10-21 08:05:17+0000 [ESMTP,2,127.0.0.1] To: you@work2.com
2014-10-21 08:05:17+0000 [ESMTP,2,127.0.0.1]
2014-10-21 08:05:17+0000 [ESMTP,2,127.0.0.1]
2014-10-21 08:05:17+0000 [ESMTP,2,127.0.0.1]
2014-10-21 08:05:17+0000 [ESMTP,2,127.0.0.1]
2014-10-21 08:05:17+0000 [ESMTP,2,127.0.0.1] Today is the 21st Oct
2014-10-21 08:05:17+0000 [ESMTP,2,127.0.0.1] (still)
```

Also, it would be good to be able to access the "full" SMTP header - message ID, etc etc. I have of course looked at the API docs for smtp.IMessage / smtp.IMessageDelivery - but cannot see anyting pertinent? Ultimately, it would be nice to create a file (possibly 2, splitting header / body) out, with the name being somehow based on the msg ID....

Can someone explain what I'm missing please? Many thanks!

Comment: afaik, RCPT TO only accept 1 recipient, normally you need to repeat `RCPT TO: <email>` in order to send to multiple recipients. Perhaps in your case you need to do a `for/loop` to send multiple times?

Comment: Hi @Anzel... I do issue multiple RCPT TO: commands in my telnet session - but the "Recipients" object in the code above seems to have lost all but the last one...

Comment: can you provide some logging or how you debug "Recipients" object? maybe then we can look at it more closely

Comment: Cant really provide a lot... As I say, it's based on the emailserver.tac in the link above. I then modified receivedheader based on this: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-14.0.0/twisted/mail/smtp.py#L946

Comment: um... that would be hard, but just by simple comparison, seems you have put `\n\n` at end of **for_**, will replace `\n\n` with `;` helps?

Comment: Further investigation suggests my analysis of the issue wasn't quite right. It looks like my multiple RCPT to's *are* being accepted, and *are* in the recipients array... but from that point, somehow the message is split/duplicated to create a single sent message per recipient... :(

Comment: can you show how the message is split/duplicated? I have a feeling that in your list of Recipients you somehow emit each mail to each recipient... whereas it should be email to a list of recipients with the same mail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63392/discussion-between-steve-hall-and-anzel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code and output look absolutely fine.
The behaviour of recipients not *grouping* together is due to the `lambda` statement triggering `self.lines.append()` for each recipient/mail emits.

You may, however, look into changing the behaviour of `lineReceived` so you can group all **lines** on received.

Good luck and hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Anzel for your support, and my apologies if anything I have asked seems "vague" :)  But could I ask you to expand your answer? Can you advise - what do I replace the lambda with in ValidateTo (return requirements: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.mail.smtp.SMTP.html#validateTo) - and what do I need to implement and where to trigger the existing lambda, once I have all recipients?

Comment: @SteveHall, not at all. Apologized was meant to say `lineReceived`... post smtp. answer edited

Comment: Trouble is, lineReceived appends to the "line" array - which is initialized for each recipient? or are you suggesting use lineReceived to dump to file as it goes - then sort the file after to strip out duplicate from lines, body etc? I'm probably misunderstanding totally here...?

Comment: no you're not. Similar approach, you can __init__ with self.from, self.to and self.body, and then you dont append lines when received. you check if self.from and self.body are the same, then only append self.to, until no more mails received (no sure if there is a function call if no more mail is received though)

Comment: do you have any repo hosting the project code? I don't mind trying on my local machine and make some changes you want.

Comment: No just held locally sadly. Perhaps you could lift the code snippet from my post above, and add your edits as a 2nd answer / edit into this answer? Really do appreciate your support here :)

Comment: @SteveHall, I just read a few twisted smtp source code and run for a few simulation. unfortunately how `twisted` `smtp` module handles multiple recipients is to emit a message for each recipient, not even in SMTPFactory can I alter this behaviour. I am afraid this cannot be be done without some deep hacks/monkey patch on existing twisted modules

Comment: Well I guess the good news there is that it's not me being a complete idiot!? :) The bad news is.... well, exactly what you wrote! Many thanks @Anzel... I'll speak to some collaegues here, to discuss how we feel we are best to proceed - I guess either own our overloaded variants of twisted code... or maybe Twisted isn't the way forward... Unless someone else can offer anything?

Comment: Well this is the default behaviour of twisted smtp modules. the mail content only got printed out on server console. So nothing stop you to write each response to a log, and write another script to monitor the file changes, and concatenate/combine the response into one :) there are certainly possibilities there.